# Dictionary<string, object> to Dictionary<string, object>[]

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am working with a REST API from C# and utilizing RESTSharp, though this isn't really a question about REST, just some background detail.

To get the dataset I am working with I get a Returned Dictionary<string,object>.  Once I make the changes to the data I need to submit, I have to submit the data back as a Dictionary<string, object>[].  What is the simplest way of converting the Dictionary<string, object> directly to a 1 lengthed array?

I know how to do it when creating the Dictionary[] from scratch, but having a brain fart on how to do it with the regular Dictionary already created, and it has over 300 records in it, so don't really want to parse through it.

If I do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object>[] tempArray = new Dictionary<string, object>[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object>{ {"Data", Data } }
        };
```

This ends up with a Data record with the dictionary and that isn't what I want.

Another way to say this, is when I serialize the record to JSON I get back I get this:

```
{
  "rec1": "string",
  "rec2": 0
}
```

When I need to submit it back it needs to be this:

```
[
  {
    "rec2": 0,
    "rec1": "string"
  }]
```

Comment: Create a dictionary list of `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. And add the dictionary into list `dictionaryList.Add(/* Your dictionary */)`. Is this what you want? And please specify what is your `Data`.

Comment: See, brain fart.  Was so stuck on it having to stay within a Dictionary I didn't think outside of the box.  Yes, this Serializes back to the format I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting the `Dictionary<string, object>` to `Dictionary<string, object>` list/array with `Data`:

1. Create a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instance.
2. Add the `Data` into `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instance.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<Dictionary<string, object>> tempList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
tempList.Add(Data);
```

Or

Create a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instance and initialize it with the value.

```cs
List<Dictionary<string, object>> tempList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
{
    Data
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering putting this where I can accept it as the answer.  Was wondering if I should just delete the question, but this works better.  Thank you again!